# Java.nio.Files "createSymbolicLink" erases target dir contents?

Tags: linux, tomcat7, java.nio.file

I want to create a link from my webapp to a directory on the server.

I'm using the following code:

```
java.nio.file.Path link = Paths.get(dirInMyApp);
java.nio.file.Path target = Paths.get(dirOnTheServer);
Files.createSymbolicLink(link, target);
```

This works, but seems to have a strange side effect: If "dirOnTheServer" had files in it, it will be empty after the link is created!

Also, I can use the link from my app and add files to the "dirOnTheServer" directory, but if I redeploy my app, it's empty again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually createSymbolicLink does not empty the directory - undeploying a webapp from tomcat with such links will.

This can be prevented by deleting the link when the webapp is being undeployed.